# What should I enter in the hour formula to get the correct hour? (the second and minute hand seem to be working)

Tags: java

//I know it must have to do with my formula but that is the formula I was given. (except for I had to switch the cos & sin on the minute and second hand for them to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm just not seeing what I am doing wrong.

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.*;//import * Class

public class ClockComponent extends JComponent
{

    int second;
    int minute;
    int hour;
    double secondHandLength = 300;
    double minuteHandLength = 200;
    double hourHandLength = 100;

    public void setCurrentTime()
    { 

        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();


        hour = calendar.get(calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = calendar.get(calendar.MINUTE);
        second = calendar.get(calendar.SECOND);
    }   

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        int xCoord = 40;
        int yCoord = 25;



        Ellipse2D.Double clockFace = new Ellipse2D.Double(xCoord, yCoord, 700, 700);     
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.draw(clockFace);
        g2.fill(clockFace);


        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        Font font1 = new Font("Old English Text MT",Font.BOLD,30);
        g2.setFont(font1);
        g2.drawString("John Doe", 305, 680);



        g2.setColor(Color.yellow);
        Font font2 = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,30);
        g2.setFont(font2);
        g2.drawString("3", xCoord + 670, yCoord + 355);               
        g2.drawString("6", xCoord + 340, yCoord + 685);
        g2.drawString("9", xCoord + 10, yCoord + 355);
        g2.drawString("12", xCoord + 340, yCoord + 35);



        int xCenter = 380;
        int yCenter = 380;

        setCurrentTime();
        double xSecond = xCenter + secondHandLength * Math.sin(second * (2 * Math.PI / 60));
        double ySecond = yCenter - secondHandLength * Math.cos(second * (2 * Math.PI / 60)); 

        double xMinute = xCenter + minuteHandLength * Math.sin(minute * (2 * Math.PI / 60));
        double yMinute = yCenter - minuteHandLength * Math.cos(minute * (2 * Math.PI / 60));

        double xHour = xCenter + hourHandLength * Math.cos((hour + minute / 60) * (2 * Math.PI / 60));
        double yHour = yCenter - hourHandLength * Math.sin((hour + minute / 60) * (2 * Math.PI / 60));



        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        Line2D.Double secHand = new Line2D.Double(xCenter,yCenter,xSecond,ySecond);      
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        g2.draw(secHand);


        Line2D.Double minHand = new Line2D.Double(xCenter,yCenter,xMinute,yMinute);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(7));
        g2.draw(minHand);


        Line2D.Double hourHand = new Line2D.Double(xCenter,yCenter,xHour,yHour);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(15));
        g2.draw(hourHand);
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is you're having. You've simply said that something isn't working (without explaining what "isn't working" means). How does it "not work"? You know that information, and we don't. There's no reason for you not to share it. You're asking us to give you *free help* to solve *your problem* - it would be to your benefit to provide the information you already have in order to make that task easier for us.

Comment: Is there a canonical question about integer division yielding integer results?

Comment: @user3291152 "...the formula I was given", "What should I enter...", you would be able to solve your problems more easily if you did some of your work on your own. All of the issues in your code boil down to basic language and logic issues. It seems like you've just been [throwing bits of your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496035/the-formula-that-i-have-in-my-code-which-is-causing-the-error-is-the-formula-tha) at the internet every step of the way, slowly getting others to do your work for you. You would have less issues in the long run if you stopped that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things look odd:

The `HOUR_OF_DAY` property returns a value in the range 0-23, doesn't it? If you are drawing a clock you need to mod 12 to convert to 12-hour clock.

The hour hand includes PI / 60. Shouldn't that be PI / 12? There are only twelve hours in one clock rotation.

When you add a fractional hour (minute/60) you're adding zero every time because minute and 60 are both ints, so no floating point result.

Comment: It's probably safe to assume that the OP did not read the documentation for [`Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY).

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
int hour;
int minute;
...
(hour + minute / 60) // in your formula
```

Integer division is used if all operands are integers. `minute` and `60` are both integers. Change at least one of them to a `float` or `double`.

In Java, `30 / 60` evaluates to `0`, for example, while `30.0 / 60.0` evaluates to `0.5`.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier (and more accurate) to first convert the time of day to a number between 0.0 and 1.0, where 1 represents 12 hours.

But putting that to one side, you're multiplying hours by a sixtieth of a complete revolution, when it should be a twelfth:

```
xHour = ... Math.cos((hour ...) * (2 * Math.PI / 60));
```